# SQL server won't return results when I put the query in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetLatestEquipmentReading
    @SerialNo VARCHAR(50),
    @UnitNo VARCHAR(50),
    @ElementID VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT Equipcom.dbo.OIL_SAMPLE.*
    FROM Equipcom.dbo.EQUIPMENT
    INNER JOIN Equipcom.dbo.OIL_EQ_UNIT ON Equipcom.dbo.OIL_EQ_UNIT.equipmentid_auto = EQUIPMENT.equipmentid_auto
    INNER JOIN Equipcom.dbo.OIL_SAMPLE ON Equipcom.dbo.OIL_EQ_UNIT.equnit_auto = OIL_SAMPLE.equnit_auto
    INNER JOIN Equipcom.dbo.Oil_Sample_Reading ON Equipcom.dbo.Oil_Sample_Reading.labno_auto = OIL_SAMPLE.labno_auto
    WHERE Equipcom.dbo.EQUIPMENT.serialno LIKE @SerialNo
    AND Equipcom.dbo.EQUIPMENT.unitno LIKE @UnitNo   

END
GO
```

And when I try to execute it, I get no results. However, when I run the query inside the stored procedure with some test values I get results.

Even more bizarre, for some serial and unit numbers, the stored procedure works fine.

Comment: Try converting `LIKE @SerialNo` to `LIKE '%' + @SerialNo + '%'`

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Thanks for the suggestion but this has not changed any of the behaviour

Comment: Are you sure about using 'INNER JOIN' s ? Try putting 'OUTER JOIN' to test the SP once...

Comment: Are you in the right database - noting that you've hardcoded your DbName (run `SELECT DB_NAME()` to check)?

Comment: Any reason you're putting a simple sleect in a SP? There's nothing procedural in here ,and a view might be better because you can join to it, and external tools and libraries often make more sense of them.

Comment: start with pasting the query that works as is into the SP (don;t use any of the parameters) then switch them one by one until you understand which one is messing with you

Comment: I don't think this is relevant to the problem, but just wondering why you pass in @ElementID when it's not used in the query. When you say you run the stored procedure, are you calling it from SQLServer Mgt Studio, or from a program? Because if you're calling it from a program, maybe it's a permissions issue. What about if you try remarking out the "Where" part of your query, then see if you get records. If you do, then there's an issue with that part, but if not, then I suspect a permissions issue or problem with one of the joins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My hunch is that the issue is in your where clause. First off, your LIKE is going to act very similarly to an equal sign("=") because you aren't using any wildcards. If you want exact matches,  I recommend using the equal sign. Also do you want the AND? Think does each ROW need to have a serialNo that matches AND a UnitNo that matches?

```
WHERE Equipcom.dbo.EQUIPMENT.serialno LIKE @SerialNo
      AND Equipcom.dbo.EQUIPMENT.unitno LIKE @UnitNo
```

Maybe this is what you actually need. I don't know. If you'd like to give a rows of sample data and desired results, then I'd be happy to help. But I think you need to analyze your logic in the WHERE clause.

```
WHERE Equipcom.dbo.EQUIPMENT.serialno LIKE '%' + @SerialNo + '%'
      OR Equipcom.dbo.EQUIPMENT.unitno LIKE '%' + @UnitNo  + '%'
```

Comment: equality is what I want. I have tried using '=' as well, it makes no difference.

Comment: Okay so you marked mine as the answer so I hope you got everything worked out!

Comment: Yea, you were pretty much on the money

Answer (score 0):

If it works fine for some values but returns nothing for others then that's a tipoff that your INNER JOIN is returning NULL somewhere. Replace INNER JOIN with LEFT OUTER JOIN and retest.